# Copy value from one document to another document

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a collection of some documents, each with an `_id` and a `data` field.
How can I copy the value `A` of the `data` field of one document to update the value `B` of the `data` field of another document using the mongodb terminal (`mongosh`)?

I can find the value `A`:

```
$ db.mycollection.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("123") },{ _id:0, data:1 })
==> { data: [1,2,3] }
```

And I can change the value `B`:

```
$ db.mycollection.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("456") },{ $set: {data: [1,2,3]} })
```

How can I combine this two operations?

*Data:*

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("123"),
    data: [1,2,3]  
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("456"),
    data: [4,5,6]  
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Simply `db.mycollection.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("456") },{ $set: {data: db.mycollection.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("123") },{ _id:0, data:1 })} })`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) to perform such an update - update from another document within the same collection (uses MongoDB v5.0).

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
{ 
  $match: { _id: ObjectId('123') } 
},
{ 
  $set: { _id: ObjectId('456'), data: '$data' }
},
{ 
  $project: { data: 1 }
},
{ 
  $merge: { 
      into: 'mycollection', 
      on: '_id' 
  }
}
])
```

Comment: **NOTE**: The `$set` and `$project` stages can be merged to a single stage: `{ $project: { _id: ObjectId('456'), data: 1 } }`. The process and result remains same.